# Stack View Preview correct but incorrect on Build

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistackview

I am trying to learn Stack Views and running into a frustrating issue.  My app looks correct in the preview window:

[image: AppPreview]

But when I go to run the app it does not look the same:

[image: AppBuild]

Here are my current constraints:

[image: AppConstraints]

I do not have any constraint warnings.

EDIT: Stack View Settings:

[image: StackViewSettings]

Comment: What are your Stack View settings? We may also need to know what your Image View settings are as well (e.g. Aspect Fit etc...).

Comment: I have added the Stack View settings above, Both images are Aspect Fill

Comment: Shouldn't your `Distribution` property be `Fill Equally` so each `UIImageView` will be of equal size ?

Comment: I had tried 'Fill Equally' as well and that one seems to have the same behavior.  One thing to note is that it looks correct in landscape mode, it is only portrait that has the issue.

Comment: Check your constraints: `1)` Make sure the leading and trailing constraints of the `UIStackView` pin it to it's SuperView `2)` Keep the current height of the `UIStackView` `3)` `Kayaking-On-The-James` image seems to have some active constraints. What are they? They may be conflicting with the `UIStackView` attempting to set the height and width. I would remove them and only let the `UIStackView` lay out the images.

Comment: Hmm... I have added constraints to pin it to the superview and even removed all constraints except for the `UIStackView` height and it is still exhibiting the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just on the face of it, setting your stack view's width to 600 is going to cause problems. No iOS device is 600 points wide, so either that constraint will break, or worse, it will be enforced and cause other views to be laid out wrong. You should pin your stack view's leading, trailing, and top, then either pin bottom or have a static height. Then have your equal width, equal height constraints for your images.

You should also ensure that "Clips Subviews" is checked in the attributes inspector your image views.

This view hierarchy and constraints, with image view content mode aspect fill, seems to work for me:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this same configuration and I do not see any change - could it be something to do with the size of my images?

Comment: You should also ensure that "Clips Subviews" is checked in the attributes inspector your image views.